# Is one allowed to fold the corner of a book on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, books-generally

An easy way to keep a bookmark is to fold the upper-right corner of a book (aka [Dog ears](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog-ear))

Is such an action permitted on Shabbos?

Comment: I was just reading about this today. The answer appears to be yes, but I need to go back and find the article that gave the sources.

Comment: Why shouldn't this be allowed?

Comment: i think making a crease might be considered a problem of tikkun kli or something.

Comment: I was taught that making any kind of permanent crease was prohibited, which was why you're not allowed to make paper airplanes on Shabbat.

Comment: You better not read any of my books :)

Comment: This seems to be based on the two fundamental approaches to shabbat: 1- Everything is forbidden unless proven permitted. 2- Everything is permitted unless proven forbidden. In light of the fact that chazal listed 39 av melachot that are forbidden, I choose approach number 2. Please explain which melacha is performed by folding a piece of paper. (BTW, I think it's a bad practice to fold pages of book even on a weekday, but that's not a halachic issue)

Comment: @Mark, do you know anyone who claims to practice number 1 or who claims it is the right way to act? I've never heard of it. (There may be some people who *seem* as though they're practicing number 1, but I've never heard of anyone who claims to do so, or who claims that doing so is the right way to act.)

Comment: @Mark see the comment by Shmuel L for a possible reason. Either way, I think that the analysis of which possible Melacha this may fall under should usually take place in a well-formed answer.

Comment: If you're marking your place on Shabbat in order to know where you are when you continue reading on the weekday, this may be considered preparing from Shabbat to the Weekday

Comment: I would never allow someone to dog-ear a book, but that's spoken as a bibliophile

Answer (score 5):

Based on Shmirat Shabat Kehilchata Ch: 28, 16, we are allowed to fold papers but not to make toys/games, because in the case of the toys you are making a kli. The previous point (28, 15) deals on the issur of making marks, even with the nail. The example brought is to know where we are in a book.

Answer (score 3):

[HaGaon HaRab Mutzafi Shelita](http://doresh-tzion.co.il/default.aspx) says it is not proper to fold pages of Sifre Kodesh. Here is the Lashon:

> קיפול דף מנהג גרוע ולא מתאים לספר קדוש

"The folding of pages is a bad custom and is not proper for holy book."

If during the week it is Asur, it is also on Shabbat.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Shabbos. The question was may one do this on Shabbos- not necessarily to a holy book- but to a book in general.

Comment: Yeah, but it's a Kal VaHomer

Comment: No it is not. (1) Just because one shouldn't fold the page of a holy sefer, does not mean that the same applies to a regular book or magazine. (2) Just because it is a "derogatory practice", does not mean that it is halachically prohibited - during the week or on Shabbos.

Comment: Also, what is this "folding of pages" - is it referring to my case (for a bookmark)?

Comment: First of all, where is the permission to waste time reading things like that? I was speaking about a Sefer Kadosh as I said in the answer. Second, yes that is it what discussing.

Comment: (1) Where is there prohibition to read non-holy material? If there was, I have a feeling all the weekly Jewish publications would not have much business. Also, although yes, you are referring to sifrei kodesh in your answer, that is not necessarily what is being referred to in the question. (2) What?

Comment: I take that back (even though there is a source in Yalkut Yosef that I'm basing this on), but I was talking specifically talking about that. 2) The person who asked was discussing using it as a bookmark. 3) I think lehalacha he holds that it would not be proper, ergo asur.

Comment: "Not proper" and "*assur*" are very different things. It is "not proper" to honk at a car in front of you for no reason, but not necessarily is it *assur*.

Comment: Rav Peretz writes that Yesh LeHizaer, and Tov mean Lechatehila, isn't Rav Mutzafi's language more strict than that? If you want sources in Aharonim I have them

Comment: R' Mutzafi's language is not strict at all, at least not in the quote you provided. Usually, I would ask for a source that explicitly prohibits folding pages of *sefarim*, but since we have already concluded that this is all irrelevant to the question anyways as per (1), I think it is not necessary.

Comment: Rav Mutzafi is an acclaimed Sephardic Posek. If you believe that his language doesn't sound strict, I respect that opinion. I also agree that it's not an Isur on Shabbat because his language doesn't use the word Asur anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

HaRav Yishak Yosef writes straight out in Yalkut Yosef that it is Mutar.

Comment: It would be wonderful if you can provide a location.

Comment: 340:6 very likely

Answer (score 1):

I researched this after asking myself the question on Shabbat and found the answers on this page somewhat confusing -- partly due to the fact that some answers address making a mark (which the Shmirat Shabbat forbids but Yalkut Yosef permits) while the question is on folding the corner of a book.

In a [comprehensive survey](https://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/shiur.asp?id=23917) of the issue, R Daniel Mann from Eretz Hemda concludes folding the corner of a page is definitely permitted. To quote the core of his argument

> Certainly, if one folds the page gently, even if the pressure on the
>   book makes the line impression stronger over time, that indirect
>   consequence is likely not considered a violation of Shabbat. However,
>   even if one presses down hard, his intention is not to make a line but
>   to create the effect of a folded page (which helps both by
>   "thickening" the page and creating a tab-like indentation at the
>   corner where the folded part is "missing.")
>
> Several authorities
>   (including Yalkut Yosef 340:6) say this is an example of p’sik reishei
>   d’lo niche lei. In other words, although the ostensibly permitted
>   action that one is doing (folding) includes a definite, direct,
>   forbidden outcome (a line), the forbidden outcome is not desired (one
>   has no interest in having a line after unfolding the page). While most
>   poskim forbid p’sik reishei d’lo niche lei, many say it is permitted
>   when the violation is only Rabbinic in the first place. (See Yabia
>   Omer V, OC 28, who is lenient. The Mishna Berura 314:11 is among many
>   who generally rule stringently).
>
> In our case, the situation is even
>   more lenient, as even purposely making the mark is permitted according
>   to many important authorities. Therefore, it is not surprising that
>   **the consensus of poskim is that it is permitted to fold the page** (see
>   Yalkut Yosef 340:6.; Shemen Afarsimon 7; Piskei Teshuvot 340:19).

See also [here](http://dinonline.org/2017/06/28/bookmarking-ages-on-shabbos/) from dinonline. They specifically address the possible concern of *hachana* (prohibition to prepare on Shabbat for the week) and write "regarding *hachana*, that is also not a problem because it might be needed for today as there is a possibility that you might want to look it up again."

Answer (score 0):

The Shulchan Aruch 340:5 writes that one can mark a sefer with one’s 
nail since it isn’t something which lasts. However, the Magen Avraham 
notes that the Mahrshal differentiates between klaf (parchment) and 
regular paper. Parchment being mutar since it’s a hard material and 
paper which is soft should be assur since the marking is something
which will last. The Shevet Hakehasi explains that bending the corner 
of the page of a book is different since one doesn’t need the crease 
rather one wants the corner to be bent so he knows what page they were
on. He concludes that it is mutar. [He notes that Rav Tzadok Hakohen 
from Lublin was makpid not to bend the corners of any of his seforim 
because of the kavod of the seferoim]. (Shevet Hakehasi 1:130)