How to remember something on Shabbat for after Shabbat (Torah related)
I am looking for some advice on how to remember something one thought of during Shabbat, but can't pursue at the time (such as a question to ask on Mi Yodeya!).
Any and all tips welcome, from memory techniques to practical solutions. I've had many questions occur to me on Shabbat, which I have subsequently forgotten until much later (and some seem gone for good, sadly).

Are you asking about the propriety of Scrabble tiles, the utility of leaving a sefer open to a certain page, or the practicality of telling others so that they can help you remember?

@rosends the one semi-condition on the question is how to remember a question one wants to ask on Mi Yodeya. Anything that helps with that. Asking others to help you remember is probably a little too obvious an answer and doesn't necessarily work very well anyway

https://www.bookdarts.com/

@Eliyahu see my other question :) https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/138469/halachicly-sound-ways-to-bookmark-on-shabbat?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C77.6198

If the thought is written in a book, one can use a book mark or book darts as suggested in the comments. Repeating the thought a few times over Shabbos can work.
If one has a short memory and one needs to remember a vort, a thought, or an idea, one could try to remember by association. To build association, one can place a book in a wrong but visible spot and state (mentally or out loud) a specific sentence related to the thought that needs to be remembered. It is also good to repeat the sentence few hours later when looking at the misplaced book, and again few hours later if necessary. One can use a cup or other non-muktzeh object. This way after Shabbos, when looking at the misplaced object one will remember what needs to be recalled due to the built association.
If one needs to remember several ideas - one may need to build several associations.
I found one of the hardest things to remember is the rabbi's speech in the synagogue during shabbos or a holiday. The problem comes with kiddush, social speaking, and long conversations during meals on other topics, which fully divert attention and erase the memory. To remember, one can try repeating important points after prayer, also try to speak with people on the subject that needs to be remembered, and of course, try to speak about the idea by the meal afterwards. Repetition builds necessary traces in memory and makes the ideas easy to recall.

What is a vort? (I’ll delete this comment if it’s a typo)

@QwertyCTRL. it's yiddish for "word" or a short Torah-based story, dvar Torah, etc.
